# python list comprehension - use of any

Tags: python, list-comprehension

```
test_list = [(1, 4, 6), (5, 8), (2, 9), (1, 10)] 
 
tar_list = [6, 10]
```

From test list keep tuples that contain any of the target list elements:

```
Filtered tuple from list are : [(1, 4, 6), (1, 10)]
```

My code to accomplish above simple task:

```
lst =[]
for tup in test_list:
    for i in tar_list:
        if i in tup:
            lst.append(tup)
```

List comprehension solution:

```
res = [tup for tup in test_list if any(i in tup for i in tar_list)]
```

Can anyone explain what purpose does "any" serve here?
1st round - tup -> 1,4,6
if cond returns true for tar_list[0] i.e 6 and then it check for value 10 at tar_list[1] it returns false. If I don't use ANY then false is considered and tup should not be in the final list res. Is that correct? I kind of understand the any usage here, but want to understand why in that case first tuple would be in res list.

Comment: "want to understand why in that case first tuple would be in res list" - please share the code with the changes you made and that's giving you the results you have trouble understanding.

Comment: I don't think you got it right. `any()` will iterate over a series of elements and return true if at least one element has a truthy value, false otherwise. If you don't use `any()` there, you'll be left with `if (i in tup for i in tar_list)`, which will always return true because the generator is not "falsy".

Comment: In case of for loop correct output is : [(1, 4, 6), (1, 10)]   And for list comprehension without "any" clause is returning  [(1, 4, 6), (5, 8), (2, 9), (1, 10)]. But when we use "any" clause it returns correct output as for loop. I have shared the code above for "for loop" as well as list comprehension. I hope I am clear this time. Thank you.

Comment: @Reti43 does not true/false depend on whether  'i is in tup' or not?.

Comment: You keep saying "without `any`", but if you remove `any`, the remaining expression is a generator, which always evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.  What don't you understand about the `any` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider your nested for loop:

```
for i in tar_list:
    if i in tup:
        lst.append(tup)
```

That will iterate over the values in `tar_list`, and if *any* of them are in the current `tup` value, that `tup` value will be added to `lst`

As a list comprehension, you write that condition as

```
if any(i in tup for i in tar_list)
```

Now these results are *only* the same if each `tup` value contains only one value from `tar_list`. Consider this case:

```py
test_list = [(1, 4, 6), (5, 8), (2, 9), (1, 10)] 
tar_list = [4, 6]
```

In this case, your original loop will append the first tuple to the output twice, while the list comprehension will only append it once.

```py
lst =[]
for tup in test_list:
    for i in tar_list:
        if i in tup:
            lst.append(tup)
print(lst)

lst = [tup for tup in test_list if any(i in tup for i in tar_list)]
print(lst)
```

Output

```
[(1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 6)]
[(1, 4, 6)]
```

You can prevent that repetition by the original loop by adding a `break` after appending to the `lst`:

```py
lst =[]
for tup in test_list:
    for i in tar_list:
        if i in tup:
            lst.append(tup)
            break
```

If you actually want to append the tuple to the output list twice, you need to modify your comprehension to be *exactly* the same as your original loop:

```py
lst = [tup for tup in test_list for i in tar_list if i in tup]
```

Output (for the above data):

```
[(1, 4, 6), (1, 4, 6)]
```

Answer (score 0):

`any` just checks if any values in the list evaluate to true. If you just wanted to filter to a single `tar_value`, this would be simple: just use list comprehension filtering `[tup for tup in test_list if tar_value in tup]`.

However, you want to check if **any** of the values in `tar_list` exist in `test_list`. So the section `i in tup for i in tar_list` just runs the above test for every element in `tar_list`. Since you want to keep element that have 6 **or** 10 in them, you use any to check if any elements returned true. If you wanted to check if 6 **and** 10 where in the element, you would instead use **all**.

Answer (score 0):

`any()` will go through a boolean iterator and perform an `or` operation (not exactly, but close enough) among the elements. Thus, if it finds 1 or more `True` values, then it returns `True`, else will return `False`

```py
tup = (1, 10)
tar_list = [6, 10] 

print([i in tup for i in tar_list])
# Output: [False, True]
print(any([i in tup for i in tar_list]))
# Output: True
```

So `any()` returns a boolean. Now see your code

```py
res = [tup for tup in test_list if any(i in tup for i in tar_list)]
```

You're doing a list comprehension, and with an `if` condition. For each of the tuples you go through the `test_list` you check if any of the elements in the `tar_list` are present in the tuple. If so, you get a `True` and you add it, else you get a `False` and you don't add it.